# Can infrared light be sent to long distance?

Tags: infrared-radiation

I need to send infrared light from its emitter to a distance of about 10-12 feet. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

It will depend on the strength (intensity) of the infrared light being emitted and the sensitivity of the receiver or detector, but a range of 10 ft is well within the range of most TV remote controls for example.

In 1917 the

> British develop the first infra-red search and track (IRST) in World War I and detect aircraft at a range of one mile (1.6 km).

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared)

This is just detecting the presence of infrared radiation rather than sending a single, but it shows that the range of several km isn't a problem.

Comment: Thankyou. I am using the infrared light which is taken out from my remote control. When I see its light using a camera, it does not go longer then some centimeters.

Comment: I was also reading the same Wiki article. I saw that there is a infrared called far infrared. I am Googling if that could solve the problem.

Comment: I am not using a receiver. I would be using a camera to detect it but the camera would detect the light from its back

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is possible. Here is the proof:https://www.youtube.com/watch?NR=1&v=LUGck9mNMDA&feature=fvwp